# 5x5 grid with no tetrominoes containing repeating colors

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, polyomino

Paint the cells of a 5x5 grid with  colors, such that every possible [tetromino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) found in the grid uses 4 different colors. What is the smallest value of  possible in such a coloring?

[Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106814/4x4-grid-with-no-trominoes-containing-repeating-colors) is a similar question for trominoes in a 4x4 grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can achieve

> 8 colors

with the following pattern:

> [image]

This is optimal because:

> In the portion of the grid highlighted below, all eight cells must be distinct colors, since each of them is within 3 steps of all the others.
>
>  [image]

(In fact, this pattern can tile the plane - there's no need to restrict it to a 5×5 grid.)

Comment: I failed to notice the specific shape at first, so I went a long-winded way. Also interesting that the final results are different.

Comment: Nicely done! Interesting that this can tile the plane.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> **8 colors**

which can be achieved by coloring the grid like this:

> ```
> 1 4 8 3 1
> 5 6 2 7 4
> 8 3 1 5 8
> 2 7 4 6 3
> 1 5 8 2 1
> ```

First, consider the

> plus-shaped region of 5 cells in the center. Every pair in this region is part of a T-tetromino, so we use 5 colors here.
>
> ```
> ? ? ? ? ?
> ? ? 2 ? ?
> ? 3 1 5 ?
> ? ? 4 ? ?
> ? ? ? ? ?
> ```

Then consider the

> center 3x3 region. All the pairs except the opposite corners are part of some tetromino, so we need two more colors here.
>
> ```
> ? ? ? ? ?
> ? 6 2 7 ?
> ? 3 1 5 ?
> ? 7 4 6 ?
> ? ? ? ? ?
> ```

Finally, consider the

> cell on the middle of a side of the grid. For all sides, the cell can be part of a tetromino with all seven colors already used, so it must have the 8th color:
>
> ```
> ? ? ? ? ?
> ? X X 7 ?
> 8 X X X ?
> ? X X 6 ?
> ? ? ? ? ?
> ```

The rest can be filled as in the top grid.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum is

> 8, attained as follows:

> [image]

Comment: Lighter colors are not easily distinguishable. I guess you could add a 3rd color hue (something like yellow or green) or annotate with letters/numbers.

Comment: I added numbers.